# Angular Node.js mysql like dislike button

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular

I'm creating a YouTube style (like-dislike) buttons for my twitter like website.
But i had a problem with implementing like-dislike buttons ,  i am using Angular Node.js MYSQL , with NgFor loop and ngIf condition ,i had two tables posts{post_id, user_id,description} and likes{like_id, user_id, post_id, like_status} with common keys user_id, post_id.

If we don't have any values of particular user in likes table how can we write the condition to show the basic button

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index ">
   <h6> {{post.description}} </h6>
   <div class="row">          
     <div class="col-md-3">
       <div *ngFor="let like of likes; ">

         <div *ngIf="((post.user_id==like.user_id) && (post.post_id==like.post_id) && (like.like_status=='like'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>

         <div *ngIf="((post.user_id==like.user_id) && (post.post_id==like.post_id) && (like.like_status=='unlike'))">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>

<!---problem with ngIf condition -->
       <div *ngIf="ngIf condition">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-basic" (click)=likeSubmit(post.user_id,post.post_id)><i
                    class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>
```

First two ngIf conditions are working good but i am unable to put perfect ngIf contion for last one , if button like_status == like, & like_status==unlike working good , if we don't have any values in like table how can we write ngIf condition o show the button

Answer (score 0):

You are doing that a little bit incorrectly, you don't need to perform inner loop in your template, you can perform just join of two tables in your component logic, and afterwards just render required data. Try to add method into your component that joins two tables, and then you can easily do what you want in template. Example:

### Ts File

```
...
    public getPostsWithLikes() {
        this.posts.map(post => {
            const like = this.likes && this.likes.find(plike => post.user_id === plike.user_id && post.post_id === plike.post_id);
            return {post, like};
        });
    }
...
```

### Html file

```
<div class="container" *ngFor="let item of getPostsWithLikes(); let i = index ">
   <h6> {{item.post.description}} </h6>
   <div class="row">          
     <div class="col-md-3">
         <div *ngIf="item.like && item.like.like_status=='like'">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)=likeSubmit(item.post.user_id,item.post.post_id)><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>

         <div *ngIf="item.like && item.like.like_status=='unlike'">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" (click)=likeSubmit(item.post.user_id,item.post.post_id)><i class="fa fa-thumbs-up"
                    aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>

<!---if you don't have related record in likes table, like would be null (false), so you just need to invert it-->
       <div *ngIf="!item.like">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-basic" (click)=likeSubmit(item.post.user_id,item.post.post_id)><i
                    class="fa fa-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
              </div>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i am getting erro in ts file  "Shadowed name: 'like'tslint(no-shadowed-variable"


PostsComponent.html:23 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at posts.component.ts:137
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at PostsComponent.push../src/app/user/posts/posts.component.ts.PostsComponent.getPostsWithLikes (posts.component.ts:136)

Comment: Edited, so looks like likes not always initialized, so i've added check before `likes.find(...)`

Comment: Can you please suggest me any other methods , i am still unable solve the error

Comment: Can you add the code of how you initialize `likes` and `posts` fields, please?

Comment: i am using two table one for posts and one for likes ,To show the post
 <div class="container" *ngFor="let post of posts; let i = index ">
 <h6> {{post.description}} </h6>
i am using above code and for every post i to display like button in three states default, like , unlike . like and unlike or working fine with above code but i am getting error while displaying default state , it means if the user didn't perform any thing , so his data will not store in the table for that i need ngIf condition for no data.please help to write the ngif condition if we don;t have any data in the table

Comment: I got it, but the solution that i provided should work, can you try it and follow up if something doesn't work? The error you posted in 1st comment shouldn't be presented now.

Comment: I tried your code in different ways when i call your methoud getPostsWithLikes()
getting errors like this

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at PostsComponent.push../src/app/user/posts/posts.component.ts.PostsComponent.getPostsWithLikes (posts.component.ts:125)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (posts.component.ts:58)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:209)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:147)
    at

Comment: when i use your code it showing nothing it means no out put So can you please use ngFor with ngIf